# Getting wrong results with implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm using PriorityQueue

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have implemented Dijkstra's algorithm using the `PriorityQueue` class of the `queue` module in Python.

But I am not always getting the correct result according to the online judge. Something must be missing in the below-given code, but I have no idea what.

What is wrong with my code?

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

class Solution:
    #Function to find the shortest distance of all the vertices
    #from the source vertex S.
    def dijkstra(self, V, adj, S):
        #code here
        q=PriorityQueue()
        distance=[-1]*V
        distance[S]=0
        visited=set()
        visited.add(S)
        for i in adj[S]:
            distance[i[0]]=distance[S]+i[1]
            q.put([i[1],i[0]])
        while not q.empty():
            w,s=q.get()
            visited.add(s)
            for i in adj[s]:
                d=distance[s]+i[1]
                if distance[i[0]]==-1:
                    distance[i[0]]=d
                elif distance[i[0]]>d:
                    distance[i[0]]=d
                if i[0] not in visited:
                    q.put([i[1],i[0]])
        return distance
            

#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3

import atexit
import io
import sys
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_cases = int(input())
    for cases in range(test_cases):
        V,E = map(int,input().strip().split())
        adj = [[] for i in range(V)]
        for i in range(E):
            u,v,w = map(int,input().strip().split())
            adj[u].append([v,w])
            adj[v].append([u,w])
        S=int(input())
        ob = Solution()
        
        res = ob.dijkstra(V,adj,S)
        for i in res:
            print(i,end=" ")
        print()

# } Driver Code Ends
```

### Sample Input for one test case:

```
9 14
0 1 4
0 7 8 
1 7 11
1 2 8
7 6 1
7 8 7
2 8 2    
8 6 6
2 5 4
2 3 7
6 5 2
3 5 14 
3 4 9
5 4 10
0
```

### Expected Output:

```
0 4 12 19 21 11 9 8 14
```

### Problem:

My code returns this instead:

```
0 4 12 19 26 16 18 8 14
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: You should provide sample input and expected output for it, and how that differs from the output you actually get. This requires from you that you do extensive tests before posting the question.

Comment: @trincot Sorry for that, Now I have updated my question with sample input and output.

Comment: Is that `.................` really part of the input?

Comment: @trincot  Nope, actually ............ means more data,

It is generated by the online judge website not me .

Comment: So we cannot use it. Can you provide *complete* input with expected output? Please note that questions on Stack Overflow should provide enough to be able to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, the online judge is not providing the whole data.
Actually, I am stuck with this code for a long hour and unable to find what's wrong with this code.

But the expected output and the code's output is mismatching at some point if you notice.
it can help you.
But sorry for not giving the complete data instead of .............. as it is not provided by the online judge.

Comment: That's why I wrote *"This requires from you that you do extensive tests before posting the question."*. You should first be able to identify a use case where your code fails. Referring to the judge is not acceptable.

Comment: Suggestion: compare the results of your code with the results from a well tested library implementation on test inputs that you generate.  Try to find the smallest graph that produces an erroneous output.  Examine the outputs to see it is obvious what causes your code to fail.  Step through your code with a debugger to find where it goes wrong.

Comment: hey @trincot  finally, I found finite input and output data.

Please have a look at this question's input and output once again.

and help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving priority to the *edges* with the least weight, but you should give priority to *paths* with the least weight.

So near the end of your code change:

```
q.put([i[1],i[0]])
```

to:

```
q.put([d,i[0]])
```

This will solve it.

However, some comments:

If you use a priority queue it should not be necessary to compare a previously stored distance for a node with a new distance, as the priority queue's role is to make sure you visit a node via the shortest path upon its first visit. With a bit of code reorganisation, you can get rid of that minimal-distance test.

Once you have that in place, you also do not need to have `visited`, as it is enough to check that the node's distance is still at -1 (assuming weights are never negative). When that is the case, it means you haven't visited it yet.

It is also a bit more efficient if you store tuples on the queue instead of lists.

And you can reorganise the code so that you only need to push the initial cell to the queue before starting the traversal loop.

Finally, instead of one letter variables, it is more readable if you use descriptive names, like `node` and `weight`:

```
class Solution:
    def dijkstra(self, V, adj, S):
        queue = PriorityQueue()
        distances = [-1] * V
        queue.put((0, S))
        while not queue.empty():
            dist, node = queue.get()
            if distances[node] == -1:
                distances[node] = dist
                for neighbor, weight in adj[node]:
                    queue.put((dist + weight, neighbor))
        return distances
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @trincot  you solved my issue.